# DataFrame.apply in python pandas alters both original and duplicate DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a bit of trouble altering a duplicated pandas DataFrame and not having the edits apply to both the duplicate *and* the original DataFrame.

Here's an example. Say I create an arbitrary DataFrame from a list of dictionaries:

```
In [67]: d = [{'a':3, 'b':5}, {'a':1, 'b':1}]

In [68]: d = DataFrame(d)

In [69]: d

Out[69]: 
   a  b
0  3  5
1  1  1
```

Then I assign the 'd' dataframe to variable 'e' and apply some arbitrary math to column 'a' using apply:

```
In [70]: e = d

In [71]: e['a'] = e['a'].apply(lambda x: x + 1)
```

The problem arises in that the apply function apparently applies to both the duplicate DataFrame 'e' and original DataFrame 'd', which I cannot for the life of me figure out:

```
In [72]: e # duplicate DataFrame
Out[72]: 
   a  b
0  4  5
1  2  1

In [73]: d # original DataFrame, notice the alterations to frame 'e' were also applied
Out[73]:  
   a  b
0  4  5
1  2  1
```

I've searched both the pandas documentation and Google for a reason why this would be so, but to no avail. I can't understand what is going on here at all.

I've also tried the math operations using a element-wise operation (e.g., `e['a'] = [i + 1 for i in e['a']]` ), but the problem persists. Is there a quirk in the pandas DataFrame type that I'm not aware of? I appreciate any insight someone might be able to offer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a pandas-specific issue.  In Python, assignment never copies anything:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 'WHOA!'
>>> a
['WHOA!', 2, 3]
```

If you want a new DataFrame, make a copy with `e = d.copy()`.

Edit: I should clarify that assignment *to a bare name* never copies anything.  Assignment to an item or attribute (e.g., `a[1] = x` or `a.foo = bar`) is converted into method calls under the hood and may do copying depending on what kind of object `a` is.

Comment: And just when I thought I was getting a decent grip on Python! Thanks much for the response. That's a big help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "why doesn't it work".  It does work.  Maybe you're confused by the variable names?  I said `e = d.copy()` because those were the names used in the original question.